# What is the function of '$' in this statement?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am doing JavaScript and found a question in the code. What is the function of '$' in this statement?

```
<td> $ <span class='output' id="payment"> </span> </td></tr>
```

Comment: It's the US dollar symbol. Don't overthink it

Comment: If its just in an HTML file, it is literally the character `$`

Comment: Nothing, it's just displaying the character `"$"`.

Comment: It means money, a modern exchange commodity

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript code is embedded between `<script>` and `</script>` or loaded into the html file with `<script src="{{url}}"></script>`.

You are just looking at html content, not JavaScript.

Comment: You are over analyzing this. It has nothing to do with scripting, it's just a $ sign to indicate currency.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I overthink it..>_<